# How to create react native firebase dynamic links?

Tags: react-native, firebase-dynamic-links, react-native-firebase

I am working on react native app. My app is having login and signup page. After signup I am sending an email to user to verify account. User will get a link to verify account, after clicking on that link I am redirecting user to url where I am verifying him. Now I want to redirect the user inside "my app" verification screen if he is verifying using mobile phone.

Is this possible with Firebase Dynamic Links??

I have created firebase project and integrated with my android app. After this I have created dynamic link for my app using firebase console:: "https://myapp.page.link"

Now I am having this section on firebase console::
[image]
After this I clicked on "New Dynamic Link", but able to add deep link and next settings. What should be the deep link for my case and where it used??

[image]

Inside AndroidManifest.xml file I have added this intent activity::

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:launchMode="singleTask"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
```

and intent-filter as follows::

```
<intent-filter android:label="filter_react_native">
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
  <data
      android:scheme="https"
      android:host="myapp.page.link" />
</intent-filter>
```

After this I have open this url in chrome(in my mobile):: "http://myapp.page.link", but it shows Invalid dynamic link because I have not completed deep link section. You can check the screenshot::

[image]

1. Please tell me what will be deep link for my case and where it used??
2. What are the other required changes I have do inside AndroidManifest.xml?
3. What react native code I need to add to redirect user inside specified screen on opening this url?

Comment: Did you try this? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zra2DCd0DnY